# C# WebAPI rendering PDF with Splash screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have a WebAPI that works wonderful. We generate a PDF on our server based on data from our DB and sometimes, these are quite large and take a while. A while = maybe 30 seconds.

Is there a way of returning a splash screen to the user while the PDF is generated and when the PDF is complete, then re-inject the stream to the HTTPResponseMessage after it has already returned a "Loading..." screen?

Comment: Sounds like you're mixing front-end responsibilities with back-end responsibilities. Your frontend should display a splash screen while it is waiting for the request to finish; this isn't the Web API's responsibility.

Comment: Problem is that the front-end directs the user to a page and that made is where the pdf is displayed. i.e. http://myhost/api/makeapdf/{id} -- the pdf is generated from that information. That is the front end.

Comment: You have to modify WebAPI as async, and update a token flag in Database that PDF creation process is start, at the same time, client application read the database token flag, and display the "Loading..", and also continious  waiting for the response from WebAPI(as it is async), when finally processing done by WebAPI then send the final response to client,now client application display the final pdf.

Answer (score 1):

http://signalr.net/ could be a nice solution to this. Having a request wait for 30 sec is usually not a good solution